# Error when remove value of tag <tr>

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery('.chk').click(function(){
   for(var k=0; k<2; k++) {
      deleteRow(k);  
   }                       
});
```

And function deleteRow()

```
function deleteRow(id) {
    var table = document.getElementById("modem_list");
    var rowName = 'row_'+id;
    if (table.rows.namedItem(rowName)) {
        table.deleteRow((table.rows.namedItem(rowName).rowIndex));
    }
}

<table id="modem_list">
   <tr name="row_1">Test 1</tr>
   <tr name="row_2">Test 2</tr>
</table>
<a class="chk" href="">CLICK</a>
```

When i click is result not delete 2 tag , how to fix it ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: You are using jQuery. No need to use native DOM methods like you do in your second code block.

Comment: where are your checkboxes? how do you define if the table row was selected or not?

Comment: (jquery with javascript)+(checkboxes which are not there)+(so many edits to post)+(use of symbols for no reason like val) --> there is something wrong in the post.

Comment: I am sorry, I has been edit code again

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You're missing `<td>`.

Comment: Does your table always have only two rows and will clicking delete always remove both rows? Will you have more than one table?

Answer (score 1):

Your whole solution may be as short as:

```
$('.chk').click(function() {
    $('#modem_list tr').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

(As of from what I can read/imagine from your question.)

Or, to only delete `TR` that have a class starting with `row_` you can use:

```
$('.chk').click(function() {
    $('#modem_list tr[class^=row_]').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

The shorter variant, without looping over the rows, may work too – but I'm not sure:

```
$('.chk').click(function() {
    $('#modem_list tr[class^=row_]').remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){

    $('a.chk').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('table#modem_list tr').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: hi, you'r right but the table syntax is wrong so the text in the tr tag in the dom is moved out of the table. anyway i will correct my answer. thx

Answer (score 0):

```
You are starting the for loop from 0 and you row id is starting from 1 thats why second one is not removing 
jQuery('.chk').click(function(){
    for(var k=1; k<=2; k++) {
         deleteRow(k);  
    }                       
});

    //  OR you can use another solution
jQuery('.chk').click(function($) {
    $('#modem_list tr').each(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
```